# Opera Form Controls Look Antiquated

Tags: opera

I recently began using opera, however I've noticed that all the form controls (and scrollbars, even the scrollbar for the page itself) look like they came straight out of Windows 98.

[image]

I am using Opera beta v. 31.0.1889.98. I was previously using Opera v. 30 (stable), and still having the same issue.

I haven't been able to find anyone else having this same issue online. I've looked through all the settings and troubleshooting, but no luck. Everything else seems to be working fine.

**EDIT:** For anyone who is having trouble connecting the dots, I outlined an issue above and so the obvious question is... how do I solve this issue?

Blocky scrollbars and form elements like that are not normal. Here, I even did a google image search for those who don't know what scrollbars should look like:

[image]

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How do I fix it :)

Comment: Fix it to what? Comments are not necessary, edit your question.

Comment: Uhm... that's how Mantis looks. On any browser. It uses plain, unstyled form elements. Are you seeing different results in other browsers? On other platforms? If so, how are they different?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Plain unstyled form elements, and the scrollbar for the page on the right, shouldn't look like that though. Here's a screenshot from Firefox of the exact same page (and every single browser I've tested looks very similar): http://vgy.me/ippgbW.png "Unstyled" just means the browser applies the default style... except for some reason, Opera isn't.